# Creating an inline table function to strip HTML

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create an inline table function to strip out HTML (so that I can `CROSS APPLY` it with another table). We have a scalar function in place, but the performance is just not good enough.

I'm really new to using T-SQL, so I don't know that many good practices of it, so if anyone has any suggestions, please let me know!

This is what I have so far:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION StripHTML
(   
    @text VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
    WITH BracketIndexes (startIndex, stopIndex) AS (SELECT
            CHARINDEX('<', @text),
            CHARINDEX('>', @text) UNION ALL SELECT
            CHARINDEX('<', @text, stopIndex + 1),
            CHARINDEX('>', @text, stopIndex + 1)
        FROM BracketIndexes
        WHERE startIndex > 0 AND stopIndex > 0
    )
    SELECT * FROM BracketIndexes
```

Now that I have the indices of where the `<`s and `>` are, I'm not sure how to:

- remove the contents between those indices
- return the string so I can cross apply it

I'm thinking I can just concat the left side and right side of each bracket using `LEFT`/`RIGHT`, but I can't seem to get the indices correct.

Edit:

This kinda worked:

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(100) = 'HELLO <B>WORLD</B> asd';

WITH BracketIndexes (startIndex, stopIndex) AS (
    SELECT
        CHARINDEX('<', @text),
        CHARINDEX('>', @text)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CHARINDEX('<', @text, stopIndex + 1) - (stopIndex - startIndex + 1),
        CHARINDEX('>', @text, stopIndex + 1) - (stopIndex - startIndex + 1)
    FROM BracketIndexes
    WHERE startIndex > 0 AND stopIndex > 0
)
SELECT @text = LEFT(@text, startIndex - 1) + RIGHT(@text, LEN(@text) - stopIndex)FROM BracketIndexes WHERE startIndex > 0 AND stopIndex > 0
SELECT @text
```

But when when I added some more HTML statements into `@text`, the `RIGHT` had an incorrect length parameter.

Comment: I don't know why but immediately I recall this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5070879

Comment: Hah, love that post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right path.  With each recursion of the CTE, you want to basically replace one HTML element with a blank using a combination of REPLACE() and SUBSTRING():

```
DECLARE @text varchar(max) = '<a href="">Cool!</a><b>oh yeah!</b>'  

;WITH BracketIndexes (rowNumber, original, startIndex, stopIndex, replaced) AS (SELECT
        1,
        @text,
        CHARINDEX('<', @text),
        CHARINDEX('>', @text),
        REPLACE(@text,SUBSTRING(@text,CHARINDEX('<', @text),CHARINDEX('>', @text)),'') UNION ALL SELECT
        rowNumber+1,
        replaced,
        CHARINDEX('<', replaced),
        CHARINDEX('>', replaced),
        REPLACE(replaced,SUBSTRING(replaced,CHARINDEX('<', replaced),CHARINDEX('>', replaced)),'')
    FROM BracketIndexes
    WHERE startIndex > 0 AND stopIndex > 0
)
SELECT TOP 1
    replaced
FROM 
    BracketIndexes
ORDER BY RowNumber DESC
```

Comment: THANK YOU! There was a small typo though. `SUBSTRING` expects a length for the second parameter instead of an index, so I used `CHARINDEX('>', replaced) - CHARINDEX('<', replaced) + 1` instead of `CHARINDEX('>', @text)` and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this very simply. Ofcourse not fully tested

```
declare @str varchar(max)='<table><th>abc</th><tr><td>def</td></tr></table>'
select @str=replace(replace(@str,'<','~<'),'>','>~')
select * from dbo.split('~',@str) where value<>'' and SUBSTRING(value,1,1)<>'<'
```

Consider it as a logic only. Surely cases may fail